# Overriding MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION in order to use @JsonView more efficiently

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

If in a Spring Boot application, `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` is disabled by default, is there some way to selectively say that a particular set of classes, I want all properties serialized without adding an `@JsonView` annotation to each property of that class?

I don't want to enable `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` because I do like the fact that properties are not serialized by default for some of my larger classes, but some common classes like a City or a State, I don't want to annotate all the properties.  I just want them to always serialize to JSON.